# UEFI programming EFI_USER_MANAGER_PROTOCOL

Tags: c, uefi

I use following command to locate `EFI_USER_MANAGER_PROTOCO`L:

```
Status = gBS->LocateHandle(ByProtocol, &gEfiUserManagerProtocolGuid, NULL, &bufferSizeu, handlesu);
```

I get `EFI_ERROR - EFI_NOT_FOUND`.

Now i try to install protocol and then open protocol:

```
  Status = gBS->InstallMultipleProtocolInterfaces (&ImageHandle, &gEfiUserManagerProtocolGuid, NULL, NULL);
```

Protocol open successfully and i try to call function `current()`:

```
Status = users->Current(users, &User);
```

Computer freezes and no show any errors.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem you need to check how you call InstallMultipleProtocolInterfaces - it looks like you did not provide the protocol instance (actually you provided NULL). Therefore when you locate the protocol instance you locate what you placed there, i.e. NULL, so your "users" variable is NULL and the system hangs when you use it.

Please find in UEFI spec the description of InstallMultipleProtocolInterfaces:
The first item (after Handle) is always a pointer to the protocol’s GUID, and the second item is always a pointer to the protocol’s interface. These pairs are used to call the boot service InstallProtocolInterface() to add a protocol interface to Handle.

I would do something like:

```
Status = gBS->InstallMultipleProtocolInterfaces (
    &ImageHandle,
    &gEfiUserManagerProtocolGuid,
    &mUserManager,
    NULL);
```

where mUserManager would be your protocol interface structure. Since you own the protocol interface, you can verify if the address of the located protocol points to the actual location of the structure.